# How to aggregate on first value in postgres sql?

Tags: postgresql, group-by

In this postgres query

```
SELECT
    q.*,
    q.user_id = 1 mine,
    first(u.username) username,
    sum(case when v.answer=0 then 1 else 0 end) no_count,
    sum(case when v.answer=1 then 1 else 0 end) yes_count
FROM question q 
JOIN "user" u ON q.user_id=u.id
JOIN vote v ON v.question_id=q.id
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY q.date_created desc 
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0
```

It says I need an aggregate on `username`. In this case, I am getting questions, and each question is created by some user. I join on votes, but group by the question id, so before grouping the username field will be the same for each unique question. So that means when aggregating, really I can pick any value since it's all the same. However I can't find any aggregate function to use. I tried random, first, last, any, but none work or even defined.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Just add `username` to `group by` clause and dont aggregate at all.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so problem is that sql engine doesn't know that `username` will be always the same. In other words it can't tell relation one-to-one from one-to-many between `guestions` and `users`. You could use `string_agg()` with `DISTINCT` like `string_agg(DISTINCT u.username, ','::text)`. What that functions does is it's aggragetes text values into one big string seperated by specified delimiter (in my case comma). When you add `DISTINCT` it takes only unique values. Since you've said theres always only one username per question the output will be that single value.

The whole query:

```
SELECT
    q.*,
    q.user_id = 1 mine,
    string_agg(DISTINCT u.username, ','::text) username,
    sum(case when v.answer=0 then 1 else 0 end) no_count,
    sum(case when v.answer=1 then 1 else 0 end) yes_count
FROM question q 
JOIN "user" u ON q.user_id=u.id
JOIN vote v ON v.question_id=q.id
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY q.date_created desc 
LIMIT 20;
```

Footnote: I dropped the `OFFSET 0` because it's default value for `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

From the box postgresql do not allow or cant do such operations, but there is workaround.

You can extend aggregate functions First/Last by this method: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)

There is plugin and portable sql version for postgresql.